# Card game, cannot divide cards to two players

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So, I have a project about building a WAR card game in react, the game is simple-
Full deck of cards equal to 52 cards.
the 52 cards need to be split into 26 cards for the player and computer.

the player is an object that have properties for example :

```
{name:'Oded', wins:0, loses:0, gamenumber:0,deck:[]}
```

at start you need a "login" main page where the user write his name press a 'START' button after the user pressed the button the system need to 'split' the fullDeck to 26 cards each. for the Adding player issue i used this function :

```
      let addPlayer=(name)=>{               //Sending the function to /Home to get the name of the new player 
    setPlayers([...players,{name: name, wins:'', loses:'', gamenumber:'',deck:[]}]) //Insert the new player into my array
  }
```

for splitting the cards deck i used this function :

```
  let newPlayerDeck=[]
  let newaiPlayerDeck=[]
  let devideCards=()=>{
    for(let i=0;i<fullDeck.length-26;i++){              //Getting two decks of 26 cards. 26 for ai 26 for player
    newPlayerDeck.push(fullDeck[i])
    setPlayers(players[0].deck=newPlayerDeck)
    }
    for(let i=26;i<fullDeck.length;i++){
    newaiPlayerDeck.push(fullDeck[i])
    setAiPlayer(aiPlayer[0].deck=newaiPlayerDeck)
  }
    
  }
```

But it's not working.. the system add the deck only to the first player in this case Oded(and override the properties)
I tried to switch the 0 to 1 for the setAiPlayer and setPlayers index, tried so many thing, what am I missing ?
my goal is to get a player object with a deck after I pressing the START button. thank you, guys !

my full app component :

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './Home';
import '../app.css'


function App() {

      const [fullDeck, setFullDeck] = useState([        //Full deck cards 52 cards
        4,4,13,1,2,12,3,12,3,5,11,3,13,13,8,10,
        10,3,5,11,11,6,5,6,1,7,2,7,6,8,9,8,                //13
        7,12,7,9,9,1,10,4,2,11,6,4,                
        12,10,9,1,5,2,13,8])


      const [players,setPlayers] = useState([                         //player properties, all my players
        {name:'Oded', wins:0, loses:0, gamenumber:0,deck:[]},
        
      ])
      const [aiPlayer,setAiPlayer] = useState([         //The computer player you play against.
        {name:'Computer', deck:[]}
      ])

      let addPlayer=(name)=>{               //Sending the function to /Home to get the name of the new player 
        setPlayers([...players,{name: name, wins:'', loses:'', gamenumber:'',deck:[]}]) //Insert the new player into my array
      }
      console.log(players)


      let newPlayerDeck=[]
      let newaiPlayerDeck=[]
      let devideCards=()=>{
        for(let i=0;i<fullDeck.length-26;i++){              //Getting two decks of 26 cards. 26 for ai 26 for player
        newPlayerDeck.push(fullDeck[i])
        setPlayers(players[0].deck=newPlayerDeck)
        }
        for(let i=26;i<fullDeck.length;i++){
        newaiPlayerDeck.push(fullDeck[i])
        setAiPlayer(aiPlayer[0].deck=newaiPlayerDeck)
      }
        
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you set state is wrong:

```
    setPlayers(players[0].deck=newPlayerDeck)
```

```
    setAiPlayer(aiPlayer[0].deck=newaiPlayerDeck)
```

This is how you should do it:

```
      const temp = [...players];
      temp[0].deck = newPlayerDeck;
      setPlayers(temp);
```

Basically, when you want to change an array state, you should not mutate the array directly (use players.push() or players[0] = something for example). You should clone it, modify the clone (in my example I used temp), then use set function (setPlayers) to update the clone to state.
Keep working hard, you'll get there!